# Find one polynomial that spans the nullspace of the matrix.

Tags: linear-algebra

> Define the image $T:P_2\rightarrow \mathbb{R}^2$ by
>   $T(p)=\begin{pmatrix}p(0) \\ p(1)\end{pmatrix}.$
>
> a) Find one polynomial $p\in P_2$ that spans the nullspace $N(T).$
>
> b) Describe the value space $V(T).$

a) Since we have a polynomial in of 2nd degree in $\mathbb{R}^2$, I denoted

$$p(x)=a_0+a_1x+a_2x^2 \implies \left\{
  \begin{array}{rcr}
    p(0) & = & a_0 \\
    p(1) & = & a_0+a_1+a_2 \\
  \end{array}
\right.$$

In order to get the nullspace, I need to solve the homogenous equation

$$\begin{pmatrix}p(0) \\ p(1)\end{pmatrix}=\begin{pmatrix}0 \\ 0\end{pmatrix} \Leftrightarrow \left\{
  \begin{array}{rcr}
    a_0 & = & 0\\
    a_0+a_1+a_2 & = & 0 \\
  \end{array}
\right. \sim a_1+a_2=0. $$

Setting $a_1=t$ I get $a_2=-t$ and $a_0=0$. So the nullspace is the line $t(0,1,-1)^T.$

How do I find the polynomial that spans this nullspace?

b) The answer to this is $V(T)=\mathbb{R}^2.$ Can someone explain to me why this is?

Comment: You just found it $(0,1,-1)^T$ are the coordinates of $0+x-x^2$ in the basis $1,x,x^2$.

Comment: Okay, it was not harder than that then. Thanks. Do you have anything to teach me regarding b)?

Comment: For every $(a,b)^T$ you have that the polynomial $a-ax+bx^2$ is sent to it by $T$.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A polynomial $p$ is in the null space if $p(0) =p(1) = 0$.
This means that $x(x-1)$ divides $p$ and if it divides $p$ it's in the null space.
So $q(x)  = x(x-1)$ spans the null space. As $q(x)= -x + x^2$ this agrees (sort of) with your answer.

$3= \dim(P_2) = \dim(N(T)) + \dim(R(T)) = 1 + \dim(R(T)$ by the standard dimension theorem. It follows that $R(T)$ is two-dimensional and so $T$ must be surjective.

Comment: I don't understand how you just got $x(x-1)$. I don't see how It follows from $p(0)=p(1)=0.$

Comment: @Parseval If $p$ is a polynomial we can apply division and write that there are some polynomials $q(x), r(x)$ with $\deg(r(x)) < 2$ such that $p(x)= q(x)x(x-1)+ r(x)$. As $p(0) =p(1) = 0$ we see that $r(0) = r(1) = 0$ and as the degree is $<2$ it must equal $0$ as a non-zero polynomial has at most degree many zeroes. So $p(x) = q(x)x(x-1)$. Now $q(x)$ must be a constant as $p$ has degree at most $2$. QED.

Comment: @Parseval Or equivalently, $(x-a) | p(x)$ iff $p(a) = 0$. And so $x | p(x)$ and $(x-1)| p(x)$ and as $\gcd(x,x-1)= 1$ their product also divides $p(x)$.

Comment: Thanks! Regarding b): Where do you get 3 from? I thought $\dim(P_2)=2$? We have not covered surjectivity yet, So I don't understand your last sentence.

Comment: $P_2$ has $\{1,x,x^2\}$ as a basis. I just mean to say that $R(T)$ is a two-dimensional subspace of $\mathbb{R}^2$ so equal to the whole space. @Parseval